# Continuous function is measurable with respect to Borel sigma-algebra.

Tags: functional-analysis

There are two measurable spaces with Borel sigma-algebras on them $(X, \mathcal B (X)) $ and $(Y, \mathcal B (Y)) $. There is also a continuous function $f:(X, \mathcal B (X)) \to (Y, \mathcal B (Y)) $. Prove that this function is measurable with respect to Borel sigma-algebra.

Comment: fyi - this question was probably 'down-voted' (not by me!) because you didn't  show any work... you might want to explain what you tried, or what is confusing you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inverse image of Borel set](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432178/inverse-image-of-borel-set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(Z, \tau ) $ is topological vector space then the Borel algebra of sets is by definition the smallest $\sigma$- algebra that contains $\tau.$
So if

1. A set $A\in B(Y) $ is open then by the contnuity of $f$ the set $f^{-1} (A) $ is open hence $f^{-1} (A)\in B(X).$
2. Let $\mathcal{M} =\{ A\in B(Y) : f^{-1} (A) \in B(X) \}$ then $\mathcal{M} $ is sigma algebra that contains every open subset of $Y$ hence $\mathcal{M} = B(Y) .$

Thus $f$ is measurable.

Answer (score 0):

Use definition of continuity:

$f:(X, \mathcal M) \to (Y, \mathcal N) $ is continuous iff $\ \ \forall A \subset Y \ \ A \text{  open} $ we have $f^{-1}(A)\text{  is open} $

By definition of Borel sigma algebra you get the thesis